# Concatenating a string to a series in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

A piece of code I thought would work didn't. I wanted to add "X" to tags only if another column represented "X". However, I couldn't just say `df['Tag With X' = df['Tag'] + "X"` which I assumed I could:

```py
MaterialsReport_df['Scoring Site Including X'] = np.where(MaterialsTracking_df['# BOXES'] == "X",
                                                          MaterialsTracking_df['Scoring Site DBN'] + "X",
                                                          MaterialsTracking_df['Scoring Site DBN'])
```

This gives the error that `elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead...result = method(y)`.

I know this works when I add a `.astype(str)` to the end. I just don't understand why.

Especially because when I check on the type of both the column and the column converted to string, Python says both are still `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: could you provide the output of this command: `MaterialsTracking_df['# BOXES'].values`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
   df = MaterialsReport_df
   df['Scoring Site Including X'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Scoring Site DBN'] + 'X' if x['# BOXES'] == 'X' else x['Scoring Site DBN'], axis=1)
```

If each element of 'Scoring Site DBN' is a string, this should work.